# Abort NSUrlConnection during his "connecting" state

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

First of all, I don't think that this question already exists, but I agree there is similar posts, please keep reading.

My question is: how abort a NSUrlConnection in his "is connecting" state? I mean, after the connection is made, we can use `NSUrlConnection cancel` method to cancel requests. But how abort it in "connecting" state, before it reaches the timeout when the server doesn't provide a response (before receiving any delegate calls)?

Thanks for your time!

**EDIT**

Should I use `NSURLSession​Task` instead of `NSUrlConnection` to do that (with its method `cancel`)?

**EDIT 2 - code sample**

```
NSURLConnection* m_connection;
m_connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
if(m_connection){
    [m_connection start];

    m_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: FLT_MAX
                                               target: self selector: @selector(doNothing:)
                                             userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
    m_runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [m_runLoop addTimer:m_timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    while (m_bRunLoop && [m_runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);

    [m_connection cancel];
}
```

I use my connection to stream data. As you can see, for now I abort my connection setting `m_bRunLoop` to `false` and it's ok. But my question is : how abort my connection before the server send an response, without wait for the entire timeout?

Comment: can you post the code where you create the `NSURLConnection` instances and where you want to cancel them, is that made in the same class or different classes?

Comment: I edited my post, different class or the same doesn't matter, I can handle that.

Answer (score 1):

You can still call `[NSURLConnection cancel]` to cancel connection and have no further delegate calls. Remember that you have to create a new connection object if you want to reconnect. From your question I deduce rather that you have a problem how to make this `cancel` call before receiving any delegate calls, is that the case?

Also, consider using [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession) API with data tasks as this is probably better way to handle networking in most cases.

EDIT (as you added code):

First of all, note that adding a timer to your run loop doesn't change anything in here as NSTimer is not considered as input source for the run loop (if you really "do nothing").

Second - if you set m_bRunLoop to false you do it somewhere, though you didn't provide the code - but this will be the place to cancel your connection, so let's name this place "cancelConnection" method.

Modify your code as follows:

```
m_connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
if(m_connection){
    yourConnectionThread = [NSThread currentThread]; // store your thread in instance variable
    [m_connection start];

    m_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: FLT_MAX
                                               target: self selector: @selector(doNothing:)
                                             userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
    m_runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [m_runLoop addTimer:m_timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}
```

and implement method where you cancel connection, remember that you need to call cancel on a thread on which you started connection:

```
- (void)cancelConnection {
    //m_bRunLoop = false <- this was before here
    [m_connection performSelector:@selector(cancel) onThread:yourConnectionThread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

}
```

Last, but rather as a comment - remember that NSRunLoop is not thread safe and you should not call it's methods from different threads.

Comment: Yes my problem is to cancel it before receiving any delegate calls, exactly!

Comment: Then this is the issue of your code architecture. As a fast patch you can store all `NSURLConnections` started in some `NSDictionary` instance variable of your class that performs requests, and when you are "in right place & time" to cancel the connection, pick right one from the dictionary and call `cancel` on it.

Comment: Well, to talk about architecture, I have a `NSThread` which makes some initializations then starts the connection (used for stream data), I want to be able to abort connection at any time because the problem is that I need to do a "join" on this thread, and I don't want to wait for timeout to be reached.

Comment: can you post the code where you create the `NSURLConnection` instances and where you want to cancel them, is that made in the same class or different classes? You have to store the reference to `NSURLConnection` so later you can cancel it.

Comment: Thank you for your advises. I'll try it later and keep in touch !

Comment: @N0un did you try it?

Comment: I'll try it soon, I'm ending an other project and I'll get back to this one soon. Don't worry, I'll inform you, sorry for delay.

Comment: I'm coming from the past, I can continue my project now. Problem is: when I call  `cancelConnection` on the connection thread as you mentions, I need this call precede a `join`and this `join` should be unlocked "immediately". This is probably an architecture issue: it is possible that `[m_connection start];`takes a long time and I really have to quit my thread during this time too. I hope I'm understandable?